# Why are the query plans different on psql and pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

For a same query, I generate the query plan using explain analyze on psql and using shift+f7 on pgadmin, but the query plan are different: one has nested loops, another has not. why does this happen? thanks.

Comment: Please add the queries and both execution plans (or upload them to http://explain.depesz.com)

Comment: Looks like a different database server or different connection settings. The query plan is created server side, not client side.

Comment: Maybe a `.psqlrc` is setting non-default values for `work_mem`, `random_page_cost` etc? Or you're connectin gwith a different username with different per-user settings?